# Deploying to Heroku: MongoParseError: Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, heroku, deployment

I am having issues deploying to Heroku. I have uploaded the relevant env variables under "Config Vars" within Heroku Dashboard but am wondering why I am still getting hit with the following error below:

```
2022-07-22T06:47:59.068313+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-07-22T06:48:00.732711+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-22T06:48:00.732804+00:00 app[web.1]: > project-management-webapp@1.0.0 start
2022-07-22T06:48:00.732804+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm install && cd server && node index.js
2022-07-22T06:48:00.732805+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-22T06:48:01.693914+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-22T06:48:01.693932+00:00 app[web.1]: up to date, audited 128 packages in 601ms
2022-07-22T06:48:01.694072+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-22T06:48:01.694106+00:00 app[web.1]: 14 packages are looking for funding
2022-07-22T06:48:01.694126+00:00 app[web.1]: run `npm fund` for details
2022-07-22T06:48:01.695406+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-22T06:48:01.695406+00:00 app[web.1]: found 0 vulnerabilities
2022-07-22T06:48:02.296149+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-07-22T06:48:02.083051+00:00 app[web.1]: Server running on port 24830
2022-07-22T06:48:02.087994+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/lib/index.js:86
2022-07-22T06:48:02.088006+00:00 app[web.1]: throw new MongoParseError('Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://"');
2022-07-22T06:48:02.088007+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-07-22T06:48:02.088007+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-22T06:48:02.088013+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoParseError: Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://"
2022-07-22T06:48:02.088013+00:00 app[web.1]: at new ConnectionString (/app/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/lib/index.js:86:19)
2022-07-22T06:48:02.088014+00:00 app[web.1]: at parseOptions (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/connection_string.js:209:17)
2022-07-22T06:48:02.088014+00:00 app[web.1]: at new MongoClient (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:62:63)
2022-07-22T06:48:02.088015+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:796:16
2022-07-22T06:48:02.088015+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2022-07-22T06:48:02.088016+00:00 app[web.1]: at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:793:19)
2022-07-22T06:48:02.088016+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:379:10
2022-07-22T06:48:02.088016+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
2022-07-22T06:48:02.088016+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2022-07-22T06:48:02.088021+00:00 app[web.1]: at promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
2022-07-22T06:48:02.228355+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Below is the relevant code:

INDEX.JS

```
const express = require('express')
const colors = require('colors')
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql')
const cors = require('cors')

const schema = require('./schema/schema')
const connectDB = require('./config/db')

require('dotenv').config()

const app = express()

// MongoDB
connectDB()

// CORS
app.use(cors())

// GraphQL
app.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    graphiql: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  })
)

app.listen(
  process.env.PORT || 4000,
  console.log(`Server running on port ${process.env.PORT}`)
)
```

DB.JS

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const connectDB = async () => {
  const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI)

  console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`.cyan.underline.bold)
}

module.exports = connectDB
```

PACKAGE.JSON

```
{
  "name": "project-management-webapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm install && cd server && node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server/index.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/BIGWALDOR/project-management-webapp.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/BIGWALDOR/project-management-webapp/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/BIGWALDOR/project-management-webapp#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-graphql": "^0.12.0",
    "graphql": "^15.8.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19"
  }
}
```

I'm definitely at a loss here so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Within my .env file, the following variable, MONGODB_URI, is set to the following value = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster>.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

For security purposes, I have replaced certain values with <username> etc. in this post. I do have it defined with my credentials

Comment: insert a `console.log("mongodburi", process.env.MONGODB_URI)` as first statement after you `require(dotenv)` and check the logs if it uses the correct value ...